# Remove the Blacklisted Icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two drowdownlist.

The first one is disabled. If I have the cursor on the first dropdownlist, a icon of the cursur will be changed into blacklisted icon or similiar.

My quesion is:
*How should I remvoe the blacklisted icon when I have the cursor on the first dropdownlist?

Thanks!

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js."></script>
 
 
 <select disabled=true>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
   


 <select>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select> 
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the CSS `cursor` property for your element. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

```
<select disabled="true" style="cursor:pointer">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Or if you want to do it globally for all disabled select objects use the CSS:

```
select[disabled="true"] { cursor:pointer; }
```

Comment: You are sure that it will be working? Don't forget that I'm using bootstrap. I strongly believe that it is bootstrap that makes the cursor to show blacklisted icon.

Comment: Bootstrap just uses CSS and Javascript, so it follows the same rules, meaning you can override it with your own definitions. If you don't want to create a style for all disabled select elements, just add it to that specific one using a `style="cursor:pointer"` (or whatever cursor you want) attribute.

Comment: Can you add HelloWorld code snippet with the `cursor`? I can edit and add it as well if you're not feeling like it.